# Formula to condense the difference of two sums

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my example below:

```
Month   Payment Received   Fee
1       1,000.00           50.00
2       2,000.00           40.00
3         500.00           5.00
4         500.00           20.00
5       3,000.00           25.00
6       1,000.00           5.00
```

The formula I currently have is `=SUM(B4:B6)-SUM(C4:C6)` which calculates (500+500+3000)-(5+20+25)=3950. Is there a way to condense this formula and not use the SUM function twice? Similar to how SUMPRODUCT works.

I am aware I could simply add another column to the right-hand side, calculate "Net payment received" and SUM on my desired range there, but it would be great if there is a way to achieve this without the additional column. With the variable range I require, using a total row at the bottom of my table also isn't desirable.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B4:B6-C4:C6)
```

This works like an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) where the calculation in the brackets is repeated for each pair of cells in the two ranges i.e. B4-C4, B5-C5 and B6-C6, then the three results are added up.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Name Manager to create a range with the fees already deducted (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) assigned to `=$B$4:$B$6-$C$4:$C$6`

Now you can just sum that range using the name you gave it, i called mine SumRange: `=SUM(SumRange)`

Comment: Certainly a interesting method to do the calculation. But I feel it would be too drawn out going forwards. I plan to extend the use over a much larger range of data and constantly change the cells used.

Comment: @Noctis Oh definately! I think I just read too much into "Similar to how SUMPRODUCT works." and assumed you were looking for a non-SUMPRODUCT solution, this is just one way of achieving the end goal, by no means the most effective.